# Bounce rate for android Ecommerce App

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate bounce rate and exit rate for a particular screen(Home screen) but it is tracking splash screen in case of android . I want to remove sessions generated from Splash Screen. Actually this is screwing my logic used for calculating bounce rate because I am taking totals.screenviews = 1 in case of bounce. But if we include splash this logic become obsolete. Query that I am using for calculate bounce rate is

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(screenviews) Totals,
    date date,
    Platform,
  FROM (
    SELECT
      COUNT(hits.type) AS screenviews,
      DATE(date) AS date,
      device.operatingSystem Platform,
    FROM
      TABLE_DATE_RANGE([118356700.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01'), TIMESTAMP (CURRENT_DATE()))
    WHERE
      hits.type IN ("APPVIEW")
      AND hits.appInfo.ScreenName IN ( "Home Storefront Screen")
      AND device.operatingSystem <> "BlackBerry"
    GROUP BY
      2,
      3 )
  GROUP BY
    2,
    3 ),
  (
  SELECT
    SUM(screenviews) Bounced,
    date1 date,
    Platform,
  FROM (
    SELECT
      COUNT(hits.type) AS screenviews,
      DATE(date) AS date1,
      device.operatingSystem Platform,
    FROM
      TABLE_DATE_RANGE([118356700.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01'), TIMESTAMP (CURRENT_DATE()))
    WHERE
      hits.type IN ("APPVIEW")
      AND hits.appInfo.LAndingScreenName = "Home Storefront Screen"
      AND hits.appInfo.LAndingScreenName = hits.appInfo.ExitScreenName
      AND totals.screenviews = 1
      AND device.operatingSystem <> "BlackBerry"
      AND hits.isEntrance = TRUE
    GROUP BY
      2,
      3 )
  GROUP BY
    2,
    3)
```

Comment: Do you have to use legacy SQL? If no, I'd highly recommend to start using the [standard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) version as it's way more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, I got this right, but if I understand correctly according to your definition your bounce sessions consist of 2 `APPVIEWS` in `hits.type` per session?
You could try something like `OMIT RECORD IF NOT SUM(hits.type='APPVIEW')<=2` after your `WHERE` statements

This sums true (1)/false (0) within the session and omits the whole record/session if it is not matching your definition of bounce.

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#omit